# Pycharm is unable to detect graphics environment

Tags: ssh, pycharm, remote-server

I am new to asking questions here and am a novice linux user, so be gentle :)

I am trying to run Pycharm Professional on a remote Ubunto (18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)) machine, and have it open on my local Windows 10 Home computer.
I am aware that you can config your python interpreter to run via SSH on a remote server, but I would like to try to have the python files on the remote server and only have it display on my local laptop.

I installed pycharm professional on the remote server, and when I run

```
pycharm-professional
```

It prints out:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.

Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment
```

I looked up similar problems, and found I should first use this line:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

But when I run again, it fails with:

```
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.

Start Failed: Failed to initialize graphics environment

java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.<clinit>(GraphicsEnvironment.java:83)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:129)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:231)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:588)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:583)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:582)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1499)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(EventQueue.java:1318)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$scheduleInitUi$9(StartupUtil.java:325)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

-----
JRE 11.0.8+10-b944.31 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o.
/snap/pycharm-professional/213/jbr
2020-09-12 15:09:18,916 [     75]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - null
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferencesFactory.userRoot(FileSystemPreferencesFactory.java:41)
        at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.Preferences.userRoot(Preferences.java:457)
        at com.intellij.ide.Prefs.migrate(Prefs.java:123)
        at com.intellij.ide.Prefs.get(Prefs.java:24)
        at com.intellij.ide.gdpr.EndUserAgreement.getAcceptedVersion(EndUserAgreement.java:81)
        at com.intellij.ide.gdpr.EndUserAgreement.access$100(EndUserAgreement.java:23)
        at com.intellij.ide.gdpr.EndUserAgreement$Document.isAccepted(EndUserAgreement.java:210)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.showUserAgreementAndConsentsIfNeeded(StartupUtil.java:785)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:265)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:243)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
        at java.base/java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.add(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:66)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Runtime.java:216)
        at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$4.run(FileSystemPreferences.java:457)
        at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$4.run(FileSystemPreferences.java:455)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.<clinit>(FileSystemPreferences.java:455)
        ... 12 more
2020-09-12 15:09:18,920 [     79]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - PyCharm 2020.2.1  Build #PY-202.6948.78
2020-09-12 15:09:18,920 [     79]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2020-09-12 15:09:18,920 [     79]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux

Start Failed: Internal error. Please refer to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at 
java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferencesFactory.userRoot(FileSystemPreferencesFactory.java:41)
        at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.Preferences.userRoot(Preferences.java:457)
        at com.intellij.ide.Prefs.migrate(Prefs.java:123)
        at com.intellij.ide.Prefs.get(Prefs.java:24)
        at com.intellij.ide.gdpr.EndUserAgreement.getAcceptedVersion(EndUserAgreement.java:81)
        at com.intellij.ide.gdpr.EndUserAgreement.access$100(EndUserAgreement.java:23)
        at com.intellij.ide.gdpr.EndUserAgreement$Document.isAccepted(EndUserAgreement.java:210)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.showUserAgreementAndConsentsIfNeeded(StartupUtil.java:785)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:265)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:243)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
        at java.base/java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.add(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:66)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Runtime.java:216)
        at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$4.run(FileSystemPreferences.java:457)
        at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$4.run(FileSystemPreferences.java:455)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.<clinit>(FileSystemPreferences.java:455)
        ... 12 more

-----
JRE 11.0.8+10-b944.31 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o.
/snap/pycharm-professional/213/jbr
```

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here, I will be glad to here :)
If any details are missing, please let me know.
Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: Following @Kenster's answer, I was introduced to the concept of X forwarding. I followed the instructions in this link, and it worked well. There is a clear explanation of what X forwarding is, too.
link: https://kb.iu.edu/d/bdnt

Comment: "export DISPLAY=:0" is not going to let pycharm run on a remote display. Please [edit] your question to show how you're invoking ssh to connect to this remote system. Are you using the options to forward X? What X server are you running on your local (windows?) system?

Comment: I was actually unaware of what X forwarding is, and as described in the edit, it worked after I installed Xming. Thanks a lot @Kenster.